# Pass an object from function component to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Map class component handles location object as params

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const location = this.props.route.params;
    console.log("Map location is: ", JSON.stringify(location));
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} region={region}></MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const region = {
  latitude: 35.6762,
  longitude: 139.6503,
  latitudeDelta: 0.1,
  longitudeDelta: 0.1,
};
```

Dashboard function passes location object to Map class using navigation

```
export default function Dashboard({ navigation }) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(false);

  const onGetLocation = async () => {
    const result = requestLocationPermission();
    console.log("Request location permission response: ", result);
    await result.then((res) => {
      console.log("res is:", res);
      if (res) {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          async (position) => {
            setLocation(position);
          },
          async (error) => {
            // See error code charts below.
            console.log(error.code, error.message);
            setLocation(false);
          },
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
        );
      }
    });
     navigation.navigate("Map", location); //location is always false??
  };


  return (
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Why does location always sets to false even though it's set to current location.
I'm new to react native. Am i incorrectly using aync/await? Any kind of help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: 1. `setLocation` takes effect in the next render cycle and it never will be `true` in this function 2. You are not awaiting for `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. Move `navigation.navigate("Map", location)` in place of `setLocation(position)`

Comment: added `navigation.navigate("Map", position);` with `setLocation(position)`. That seemed to work. Thank you @Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does location always sets to false even though it's set to current location.

In fact it is not set to `false` but because it is initially `false` when you create it and here the navigation happens before the promise arrives so thats why.

you want to make the navigation happen insinde the `.then` block therefore you don't need to use the state for that just use `position` or `false` directly :

```js
if (res) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async (position) => {
        setLocation(position); // you may don't need to update the state or maybe don't need it at all
        navigation.navigate("Map", position); // you cannot use "location" here because it isn't updated yet
      },
      async (error) => {
        // See error code charts below.
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
        setLocation(false); // you may don't need to update the state or maybe don't need it at all
        navigation.navigate("Map", false); //you cannot use "location" here because it isn't updated yet
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
  } else {
    // ... hanlde the else case
  }
```